# How to do nginx redirect for dynamic page urls

Tags: nginx, redirect

I need to change nginx config in a way , that every dynamically generated request is being redirected to main domain.
I'm not sure how to achieve this. Help please!
Not sure if this matters, but I want to add, that traffic goes thru nginx reveser proxy (ssl) to simple web server (nginx)

```
https://mypage.com/something ->https://mypage.com
https://mypage.com/anything123 ->https://mypage.com
https://mypage.com/randomtext ->https://mypage.com
```

Comment: How can you tell which request needs to be redirected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have two location blocks, one for exact match of root directory and the other one for everything else.

```
location = / {
   try_files /index.html = 404;
}

location / {
   return 301 /;
}
```

`rewrite` also can be used instead of `return` (redirect), but will be slower.

```
    location / {
       rewrite ^ / permanent;
    }
```

Another option is just to have a `rewrite` for everything (inside server block), without any location blocks. In this method, url will remain as the original url you typed on the browser.

```
server {
    root /xxx/xxx/xx;
    server_name mypage.com;
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Chaminda. I trued to apply your suggestions, but in first case, pages wante to download, in second error was"the page redirects incorrectly" I try to add my config. Maybe I did not provided all needed info!

Comment: config part 1
`server {
  listen 192.168.152.32:80;
  server_name
  .mydomain.com;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  root /var/www/mydomain.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-error.log error;
  index index.php;
  if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    break;
  }`

Comment: config part 2
`  location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
  }
  location ~ .*\.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/mydomain.com$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
  }
}`

Comment: Did you try my code with 'index.php' in place of 'index.html'? i.e. 

location = / {
 try_files /index.php = 404;
}

location / {
       rewrite ^ / permanent;
}

Comment: Also, you may remove the ""if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last; break; }"" block, unless it is really needed.

Comment: Thank you! ok, I made config like this `server {
  listen 192.168.152.32:80;
  server_name
  .mydomain.com;

  client_max_body_size 10M;
  root /var/www/mydomain.com;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-error.log error;
  index index.php;

 location = / { try_files /index.php = 404;
 }
 location / { rewrite ^ / permanent;
 }
  location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
  }
  location ~ .*\.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param....like above`

Comment: then page is again downloading, This time I opened this `<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' ); `

Maybe  here is something that needs to be changed. In wordpress? Im not expert in wordpress..